# Firebase error on web token notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

I am trying to send the notification to the specific user using firebase. Going on with tutorials, I could not solve this in the beginning phase.

Here is my js:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);

 const messaging = firebase.messaging();

 messaging.usePublicVapidKey("");

 messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  return messaging.getToken();
}).then(function(token){
  console.log(token); 
})



function getRegToken(){
    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
      if (currentToken) {
        // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
        console.log(currentToken);
      } else {
        // Show permission request.
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');

        setTokenSentToServer(false);
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    });
}
```

I have inserted correct parameters inside the config and public key

[image: Error while generating token]